# Unsure how to do multiple nested SELECT statements while using GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server

Good Afternoon,

Currently I have functioning code that works for determine the number of opened work orders and the number of closed work orders during a period of time.  I now want to add the number of work orders that were opened prior to that period of time; I have the code that produces the results I want but I am having difficulties figuring out how I would have my select statement built into the initial code so I do not have to assign a static date.  It will be easier to show you what I currently have and what I expect to get.

```
SELECT o.dateinfo
    ,opened
    ,closed
FROM (
    SELECT MONTH(org_date) + (YEAR(org_date) * 100) AS dateinfo
        ,COUNT(wo) AS opened
    FROM wkaw
    WHERE org_date >= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1, MONTH(GETDATE()), 01)
    GROUP BY MONTH(org_date) + (YEAR(org_date) * 100)
    ) o
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MONTH(cmpl_date) + (YEAR(cmpl_date) * 100) AS dateinfo
        ,COUNT(wo) AS closed
    FROM wkaw
    WHERE cmpl_date >= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1, MONTH(GETDATE()), 01)
        AND cmpl_date IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY MONTH(cmpl_date) + (YEAR(cmpl_date) * 100)
    ) c ON o.dateinfo = c.dateinfo
ORDER BY o.dateinfo
```

Produces these results currently

```
dateinfo  |  opened  |  closed
--------------------------------
201502    |   285    |    587
201503    |   519    |    345
201504    |   494    |    398
201505    |   415    |    430
201506    |   578    |    465
201507    |   409    |    646
201508    |   501    |    417
201509    |   430    |    347
201510    |   491    |    983
201511    |   657    |    455
201512    |   468    |    366
201601    |   723    |   1105
201602    |    54    |     60
```

I then have the following select statements that is getting the information I would want for each of those terms but they are using static dates instead of auto-generating like I did above.

```
SELECT COUNT(wo) FROM wkaw WHERE (cmpl_date >= DATEFROMPARTS(2015,02,01) OR cmpl_date IS NULL) AND org_date < DATEFROMPARTS(2015,02,01)
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wkaw WHERE (cmpl_date >= DATEFROMPARTS(2015,03,01) OR cmpl_date IS NULL) AND org_date < DATEFROMPARTS(2015,03,01)
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wkaw WHERE (cmpl_date >= DATEFROMPARTS(2015,04,01) OR cmpl_date IS NULL) AND org_date < DATEFROMPARTS(2015,04,01)
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wkaw WHERE (cmpl_date >= DATEFROMPARTS(2015,05,01) OR cmpl_date IS NULL) AND org_date < DATEFROMPARTS(2015,05,01)
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wkaw WHERE (cmpl_date >= DATEFROMPARTS(2015,06,01) OR cmpl_date IS NULL) AND org_date < DATEFROMPARTS(2015,06,01)
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wkaw WHERE (cmpl_date >= DATEFROMPARTS(2015,07,01) OR cmpl_date IS NULL) AND org_date < DATEFROMPARTS(2015,07,01)
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wkaw WHERE (cmpl_date >= DATEFROMPARTS(2015,08,01) OR cmpl_date IS NULL) AND org_date < DATEFROMPARTS(2015,08,01)
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wkaw WHERE (cmpl_date >= DATEFROMPARTS(2015,09,01) OR cmpl_date IS NULL) AND org_date < DATEFROMPARTS(2015,09,01)
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wkaw WHERE (cmpl_date >= DATEFROMPARTS(2015,10,01) OR cmpl_date IS NULL) AND org_date < DATEFROMPARTS(2015,10,01)
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wkaw WHERE (cmpl_date >= DATEFROMPARTS(2015,11,01) OR cmpl_date IS NULL) AND org_date < DATEFROMPARTS(2015,11,01)
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wkaw WHERE (cmpl_date >= DATEFROMPARTS(2015,12,01) OR cmpl_date IS NULL) AND org_date < DATEFROMPARTS(2015,12,01)
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wkaw WHERE (cmpl_date >= DATEFROMPARTS(2016,01,01) OR cmpl_date IS NULL) AND org_date < DATEFROMPARTS(2016,01,01)
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wkaw WHERE (cmpl_date >= DATEFROMPARTS(2016,02,01) OR cmpl_date IS NULL) AND org_date < DATEFROMPARTS(2016,02,01)
```

The results for those are as follows

```
1  |  2187
1  |  1885
1  |  2059
1  |  2155
1  |  2140
1  |  2253
1  |  2016
1  |  2100
1  |  2183
1  |  1691
1  |  1893
1  |  1995
1  |  1613
```

These numbers do show what I would expect.  The results that I want to see though is

```
dateinfo  |   open_wo_count  |  opened  |  closed
---------------------------------------------------
201502    |      2187        |   285    |    587
201503    |      1885        |   519    |    345
201504    |      2059        |   494    |    398
201505    |      2155        |   415    |    430
201506    |      2140        |   578    |    465
201507    |      2253        |   409    |    646
201508    |      2016        |   501    |    417
201509    |      2100        |   430    |    347
201510    |      2183        |   491    |    983
201511    |      1691        |   657    |    455
201512    |      1893        |   468    |    366
201601    |      1995        |   723    |   1105
201602    |      1613        |    54    |     60
```

I've tried some different methods but they have all produced un-expected results and I am sure it is just because I do not know how.  Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers,
Johnathan

Comment: Updated, thanks!  Just a bad habit of mine to capitalize titles

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but I have done a rolling work order count report in the past and you need a calendar table (a table whose primary key is a date covering every date possible). Then you join that to the appropriate date fields in your work orders and the answer comes out. It may be better if you provide a simple example of input and output data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a sub select. I also had to CONVERT the dates to be able to compare them to o.dateinfo. This way you don't have to manually build the dates since they already exist in dateinfo.

```
SELECT o.dateinfo
    , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wkaw WHERE (CONVERT(CHAR(6), cmpl_date, 112) >= o.dateinfo OR cmpl_date IS NULL) AND CONVERT(CHAR(6), org_date, 112) < o.dateinfo) AS open_wo_count
    ,opened
    ,closed
FROM (
    SELECT MONTH(org_date) + (YEAR(org_date) * 100) AS dateinfo
        ,COUNT(wo) AS opened
    FROM wkaw
    WHERE org_date >= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1, MONTH(GETDATE()), 01)
    GROUP BY MONTH(org_date) + (YEAR(org_date) * 100)
    ) o
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MONTH(cmpl_date) + (YEAR(cmpl_date) * 100) AS dateinfo
        ,COUNT(wo) AS closed
    FROM wkaw
    WHERE cmpl_date >= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1, MONTH(GETDATE()), 01)
        AND cmpl_date IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY MONTH(cmpl_date) + (YEAR(cmpl_date) * 100)
    ) c ON o.dateinfo = c.dateinfo
ORDER BY o.dateinfo
```

Comment: I was way over complicating the select statement, I think if I read this correctly your statement is using dateinfo from the group by statement and then changing it into a date to generate the COUNT where clause?  That is awesome!  Thanks

Comment: I actually didn't realize after looking at all the multiple select statements that I could do a select inside a select; I thought I always had to do a select from select that's what threw me off.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You could make a table that stores all the start-of-month dates you need. (This could either be a utility table that you generate once, or it could be a temp table that gets generated on the fly.)

In your case we can probably cheat a little. **As long as each month has at least one work order in it** we can use the work order table itself to make a list of the dates we need. Something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(org_date),MONTH(org_date),01)) AS d FROM wkaw
```

I believe these are the dates you wanted. Now we select the dates from this "table" along with a subquery that counts the open workorders as of each date. Something like:

```
SELECT MONTHSTART.d,
(SELECT COUNT(wo) FROM wkaw WHERE (cmpl_date >= MONTHSTART.d OR cmpl_date IS NULL) AND org_date < MONTHSTART.d)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT(DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(org_date),MONTH(org_date),01)) AS d FROM wkaw) MONTHSTART
```

This doesn't quite give you your final query, but its pretty close. To join it back to your original query, try replacing `SELECT MONTHSTART.d` with `SELECT MONTH(MONTHSTART.d) + (YEAR(MONTHSTART.d)*100) as dateinfo` and combine that with your original query.

Answer (score 0):

If you do a cross join back to the Wkaw table, then you will get 13 duplicates of each entry in this table. You can then compare the `cmpl_date` and the `org_date` to the `dateinfo` created in either of the two subqueries before.

EXAMPLE

```
SELECT o.dateinfo
    ,SUM(Case when (cmpl_date >= DATEFROMPARTS(Left(o.dateinfo,4),Right(o.dateinfo,2),01) OR cmpl_date IS NULL) AND org_date < DATEFROMPARTS(Left(o.dateinfo,4),Right(o.dateinfo,2),01) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS open_wo_count
    ,MAX(opened) as opened
    ,MAX(closed) as closed
FROM (
    SELECT MONTH(org_date) + (YEAR(org_date) * 100) AS dateinfo
        ,COUNT(wo) AS opened
    FROM wkaw
    WHERE org_date >= @DateStart
    GROUP BY MONTH(org_date) + (YEAR(org_date) * 100)
    ) o
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MONTH(cmpl_date) + (YEAR(cmpl_date) * 100) AS dateinfo
        ,COUNT(wo) AS closed
    FROM wkaw
    WHERE cmpl_date >= @DateStart
        AND cmpl_date IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY MONTH(cmpl_date) + (YEAR(cmpl_date) * 100)
    ) c ON o.dateinfo = c.dateinfo
CROSS JOIN Wkaw W
GROUP BY o.dateinfo
ORDER BY o.dateinfo
```

You will have to take the MAX or MIN of the opened and closed counts (but these will all be the same so no issues)